# Custom view hast strange layout behavior

Tags: android, layout, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout

Basically I have a custom View-Class (`MessageViewAudio`) which extends `ConstraintLayout`. This custom view contains another `ConstraintLayout` which contains another custom view (`AudioVisualizationView`) I made myself. The problem ist that the Top-Layer-Custom View (`MessageViewAudio`) always has some space to the right. I attached the information the layout inspector gave me. If you need any more code, just let me know.

As already said, I inspected the layout and tried different types of containers and manually tried to remove margins and paddings from every view mentioned above. But the layout inspector already says that there is no margin oder padding that could cause that strange behavior. **There are two ways I got this to work** One: is to remove all containers and just add the `AudioVisualizationView` custom view. Two: is to remove the property constrainedWidth = true from the LayoutParams of `MessageViewAudio`. Now I need constrainedWidth = true but I have that feeling that this property is kind of the problem, I can't just figure out why constrainedWidth results in this behavior.

### With containers

#### Not Working

[image: The hierarchy]

#### Hierarchy

[image: The hierarchy]

#### ChatMessage

[image: The layout]

#### MessageViewAudio

[image: The layout]

#### audioContent

[image: The layout]

#### visualizationView

[image: The layout]

### Without containers

**Working**

[image: Working]

The only code I can provide for now is the xml of the views:
audioContent + visualizationView:

```
<com.jooyapp.jooy.custom_views.RoundedConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/audioContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:radius="20">

    <!--android:paddingStart="10dp"-->
    <!--android:paddingTop="10dp"-->
    <!--android:paddingEnd="10dp"-->
    <!--android:paddingBottom="10dp"-->

    <com.jooyapp.jooy.custom_views.AudioVisualizationView
        android:id="@+id/visualizationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.jooyapp.jooy.custom_views.RoundedConstraintLayout>
```

All others are created programmatically

All in all my problem is that I don't understand where this space to the right of the custom view comes.